# How to get total from grouped row

Tags: reporting, rdlc, rdl

I try to get the total hours for a Employee

My Report should look like:

```
    GROUP "Month"        | Details 

Month | WorkHoursMonth | section | Hours         STATIC
----------------------------------------         --------------
      |                |   A1    |   12         
 1    |     50         |   B3    |   38         
----------------------------------------         
      |                |   A1    |   12         
 2    |     50         |   B3    |   38         
----------------------------------------         GROUP "Month"
      |                |   A1    |   12         
 3    |     62         |   B3    |   38         
      |                |   C1    |   12         
----------------------------------------         
 4    |     38         |   B3    |   38         
----------------------------------------         --------------
Total |    200                                   STATIC Total
```

I tryed to use SUM() like `SUM(Field.WorkHoursMonth.Value,"Month")`.
but i get an ERROR

> Fehler    1   Der Value-Ausdruck für das Textfeld-Objekt 'SollStunden1'
>   weist einen Bereichsparameter auf, der für eine Aggregatfunktion
>   ungültig ist. Der Bereichsparameter muss auf eine
>   Zeichenfolgenkonstante festgelegt sein, die einem der folgenden Werte
>   entspricht: dem Namen einer enthaltenden Gruppe, dem Namen eines
>   enthaltenden Datenbereichs oder dem Namen eines Datasets.

---

### Update 1

The problem is my current Total is **424** instead of **200** but i don't know **how to make a total at the end for the group which** based on the error **has to be inside the group**.

```
    GROUP "Month"        | Details 

Month | WorkHoursMonth | section | Hours         STATIC
----------------------------------------         --------------
      |                |   A1    |   12         
 1    |     50         |   B3    |   38         
----------------------------------------         
      |                |   A1    |   12         
 2    |     50         |   B3    |   38         
----------------------------------------         GROUP "Month"
      |                |   A1    |   12         
 3    |     62         |   B3    |   38         
      |                |   C1    |   12         
----------------------------------------         
 4    |     38         |   B3    |   38         
----------------------------------------         --------------
Total |    424                                  STATIC Total
```

---

### Update 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe you might have made a typographical error:

> I tryed to use SUM() like `SUM(Field.WorkHoursMonth.Value,"Month")`. but i get an ERROR

```
=SUM(Fields!WorkHoursMonth.Value,"Month")
```

But I doubt this is the cause of your issue, based on your error message. I believe you either didn't group correctly or your group just isn't called "*Month*".
You could try to remove the scope definition and simply use the following expression, just make sure it's still inside your group.

```
=SUM(Fields!WorkHoursMonth.Value)
```

---

**Edit:** I didn't realize that the *WorkHoursMonth* was the same for all rows and not being grouped on. Who knew this would cause so many issues for trying to calculate the total...

The grouping you have set up seems to be correct as long as the *WorkHoursMonth* value is the same for the entire month, which it seems to be in your case.

The following expression should then calculate your wanted total:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!WorkHoursMonth.Value,"Month"))
```

Comment: we have looked in to it and there is no typographical error (used copie + paste to be sure), we also can't use `=SUM(!Fields.WorkHoursMonth.Value)`because the result will be **424** because `(50+50)+(50+50)+(62+62+62)+38 = 424`

Comment: But how do i do this? That's my problem

Comment: Usually the group name is displayed at the bottom-left of the designer. I don't have access to my VisualStudio right now so i cant take a screenshot but i'll look for an image on google.

Comment: I don 't know whats happening with all the "Static" stuff on your screenshot. Have you tried this?:
In the tablix data region row group area, right-click a cell in the row group area for which you want totals, point to Add Total, and then click Before or After.
A new row outside the current group is added to the data region, and then a default total is added for each numeric field in the row.

Comment: the Static stuff is normal each represents a column, And to your question that is exactly what i did rightClick Group -> Add Total -> After but here it only auto Sum Details and no GroupRow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100455/discussion-between-oceans-and-wiimaxx).

Answer (score 0):

Just use [sum(month)] place this on your total

Comment: i tryed: `[sum(month)]`,`=[sum(month)]`, `=sum(month)` but then i'm unable to compile